# Remove disabled attribute with jquery not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, attributes, prop

I'm trying to remove/add the disable attribute to my button with the id of 'register'. This is the code I've tried, but it doesn't work..

$(document).ready(function() {

```
 $('.tos').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $('.tos').is(':checked');
    if(isChecked)
      console.log("True");
      $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
    else
      console.log("False");

  });

});
```

I get this error in my console, but I have no idea what it means.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
```

This is the button I want to remove/add the disabled attribute to.

```
<button type="submit" id="register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-color btn-xxl" disabled>Create an account</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to run more than one statement if the condition is `true`, you have to put them in a block `{...}`. Otherwise it reads as http://jsfiddle.net/5bgH9/, which is clearly invalid. As you can read in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) *"To execute multiple statements within a clause, use a block statement (`{ ... }`) to group those statements. In general, it is a good practice to always use block statements, especially in code involving nested `if` statements:"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

This is because you haven't used `{}` syntax in your if statement. Not using them is fine, but only when you have **one** line to execute. In this case, your else is the second line and is breaking the "only one line without curly brackets" rule.

Use curly brackets:

```
if(isChecked) {
      console.log("True");
      $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
} else
     console.log("False");
```

Answer (score 1):

dont forget `{...}`

```
$('.tos').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $('.tos').is(':checked');
    if(isChecked){
      console.log("True");
      $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      console.log("False");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have braces around the first if body.  Should be:

```
if(isChecked) {
      console.log("True");
      $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
}
    else {
      console.log("False");
}
```

Technically the second set of braces are optional, but it's worth using them

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isChecked)
  console.log("True");
  $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
else
  console.log("False");
```

What is that?

---

```
if(isChecked){
  console.log("True");
  $('#register').removeAttr("disabled");
}else{
  console.log("False");
}
```

Now this is how you do it correctly ;)

Answer (score 1):

For `if else` statements, you can use one of these two syntaxes:

```
//either....
if (condition)
    one_action();
else
    one_other_action();
//or....
if (condition) {
    one_action()
    more_actions()
} else {
    one_other_action();
    and_some_more();
}
```

So, you can omit the `{}` around the block of actions to do when the condition is true **only** if the block contains a single action. Since you're doing a console.log *and* a jQuery function, the `if else` statements are interrupted, and JavaScript no longer recognises that you're in it. Because of that, it won't see the `else` coming. To make this work, simply put `{}` around it like the other answers show.